# karma not finding angularjs directive in its own file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine

In a file `dashboard.module.coffee` I have the following declaration:

```
angular
  .module('app.dashboard', [])
```

In another file, `stat.directive.coffee` I have the following:

```
angular.module('app.dashboard')
  .directive('stat', ['$interval', statDirective])
```

`statDirective` contains the directive logic.  This code works fine in a browser, i.e. the `<stat>` element works as expected, but the following Jasmine test does not render the element, it's simply an empty string:

```
describe "Stat", ->
  element = null
  scope = null

  beforeEach module 'app.dashboard'
  beforeEach module 'views/templates/dashboard/stat.html'
  beforeEach inject ($compile, $rootScope) ->
    scope = $rootScope.$new()
    element = $compile('<stat></stat>') scope

  it "contains some html", ->
    scope.$digest()

    expect(element.html()).toEqual('<div>hi</div>')
```

I've narrowed this down to the module being declared separately from the directive.  If instead, the declaration was like this, the directive is found and rendered:

```
angular.module('app.dashboard', [])
  .directive('stat', ['$interval', statDirective])
```

Here, the only change is that the module and directive are being declared together, not in two files.

This looks to be an issue specifically with Karma as the code works just fine in a browser.  Is there something missing in my Karma config to have this type of file structure work?

Here is my Karma configuration:

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Mon Jun 29 2015 22:33:24 GMT-0700 (PDT)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'client/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',

      {pattern: 'client/bower_components/**/*.map', watched: false, included: false, served: true},

      'client/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js',
      'client/bower_components/angular-websocket/angular-websocket.js',

      'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',

      'client/views/**/*.html',

      'client/scripts/*.module.js',
      'client/scripts/**/*.module.js',
      'client/scripts/**/*.module.coffee',
      'client/scripts/**/*.directive.coffee',
      'client/scripts/**/*.controller.coffee',
      'client/scripts/**/*.coffee',

      'spec/**/*Spec.coffee'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      '**/*.coffee': ['coffee'],
      'client/views/**/*.html': 'ng-html2js'
    },

    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
      // strip app from the file path
      stripPrefix: 'client/'
    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  })
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: post your karma.config file yoh.

Comment: @SoEzPz Question edited to include karma config, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we have to take this in steps...

I see that your directive **stat** has a dependency: $interval.

You may need to include this service to get it run right if I recall.

Can you try this?

```
beforeEach inject ($compile, $rootScope, _$interval_) ->
  scope = $rootScope.$new()
  element = $compile('<stat></stat>') scope
  $interval = _$interval_; // you may not need this line, just the inject.
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, try this as well

Change this

```
element = $compile('<stat></stat>') scope
```

To this

```
element = $compile( angular.element('<stat></stat>'))(scope);
```

Comment: I still get the same error.  By the way, there should only be a single underscore around `_$interval_`.  I was getting a completely different error until I removed the extra underscores.  Thanks!

Comment: No, with the underscore fix, I get the same results as my initial post.  :(

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed the update.  Same result using `angular.element`: `Expected '' to equal '<div>hi</div>'`